# GraalVM native-image with Java 8 build fails with error com.oracle.svm.core.hub.DynamicHub.getGenericInfo() method not available in this platform

Tags: java, javafx-8, graalvm-native-image

I am working hard to generate native-image for Windows of my JavaFX application which is compiled with Java 8 JDK. Native image is generating with graalvm 20.2.0. with --no-fallback option.

I am getting a strange message that method with name `com.oracle.svm.core.hub.DynamicHub.getGenericInfo() is not available in this platform`
It appears that, it's not possible to analyse that exactly where this issue is arising in the code.

Can somebody please direct me that what does this method actually do? I could not find any documentation.

Second thing I want to know is, if I generate native-image with fallback option, it is building the fallback image by passing main class as com.oracle.svm.core.FallbackExecutor not my Application's main class.

```
-H:Class=com.oracle.svm.core.FallbackExecutor
```

So, it needs Application jar to be exist in the build path in order to run the application successfully.
Can somebody tell me how to make native-image utility use my application's main class as the actual class to call, in order to start application-image that is generated with fallback-image method, not the FallbackExecutor.

Either of the solution will help me get going. Your proper directive help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This won't work. Gluon is providing a solution for this. Have a look here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin (But you will first have to upgrade to at least Java 11)

Comment: My application is currently ant build, how would you recommend to move it maven? I mean how to find all libraries in maven? I am new to maven.

Comment: 1. Work through some introductory Maven tutorial. 2. Try the examples provided by Gluon https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples

Comment: @mipa Ok, I will try it. Thank you